# How to have multiple environments using the same resource in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elasticache

We have the following scenario: We have three stacks of our application infrastructure in the same AWS account: QA1, QA2 and QA3. Each environment has its own EKS, RDS, Redis, VPC, etc.
We manage the environments using Terraform, and all environments should be lined up with the same infrastructure basically - same versions, etc. Each environment is managed with its own Terraform workspace.

Up until now, we've used the default parameter group for Redis. But now we need to create a custom one to change some parameter. Now, I don't need 3 parameter groups, I can create only one and point all the Redis clusters (QA1,2,3) to the same one.

The question is, how to handle such case in Terraform?

Say I have the terraform code:

```
resource "aws_elasticache_parameter_group" "this" {
  name = "my-param-group"
  ...
}

resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" {
  name = "redis-${env}"
  parameter_group_name = aws_elasticache_parameter_group.this.name
}
```

Now the problem is that, when I `terraform apply` this in the first environment, everything is OK. But when I then apply it to the second environment, I get a failure because the parameter group already exists.

Is there a good way to manage this so that the parameter group will be created only if it doesn't exist? Or must I create a parameter group for each cluster separately?

Comment: I would just create one parameter group for each environment (by making the `name` unique per environment). You aren't charged for having multiple, and at some point you may want to test changes to the parameters in one environment before rolling the change out to other environments.

Comment: To explicitly answer your question: no, terraform does not support "create if not exists". HCL is a declarative language, so you have to be explicit about what state it needs to manage. You have two options really: 1) roll out an aws_elasticache_parameter_group in each environment. 2) create an additional state for shared resources, roll out one aws_elasticache_parameter_group there and then use "data" resources to reference it in the other states.

Answer (score 0):

I this case it's better to have dedicated parameter group for each environment, but there are a few possible solutions to utilize the same AWS object:

1. Create the parameter group resource in QA1, and then import the existing AWS resource into QA2 and QA3. For further information, refer to https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elasticache_parameter_group#import.
2. Create a dedicated Terraform project for shared items. However, you must refer to those objects only by name or ARN. It's not worthwhile if you require only one shared object.